# Mosfet data sheets

Tags: transistors, mosfet

Where can I find the data on different components, like mosfet enhance n channel.
If I use a mosfet enhance n channel transistor with a threshold voltage of 14V will it turn on at 14V if so what voltage will it turn off,? 13V

Comment: You can find datasheets for MOSFETs on any FET manufacturer's website.  14V is too high for a threshold, it's normally much lower.  See the Id vs. Vgs characteristics on the datasheet to see the relationship.  A FET is not "ON" at the threshold voltage.

Comment: Thanks, where should I look to find a component that will come on at 14V and off at 13V

Comment: You won't be able to find one as it does not exist; see my answer.

Comment: Duplicate of [Switch that turns on and off with variable voltage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/470714/switch-that-turns-on-and-off-with-variable-voltage) also asked by you today.

Comment: This desired threshold switch behavior appears to be a restating of your existing question of today https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/470714/switch-that-turns-on-and-off-with-variable-voltage only with critical detail missing.  **Do not post the same problem multiple times**.  The path to a solution and the potential issues with it were *already explained* at your existing question, this tangent is not productive.

Comment: Thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

FET threshold voltage is the voltage where it has barely started to conduct. You won't be able to find a FET or other component that turns fully on at 14V and fully off at 13V, you need much more than that, a complete circuit with lots of components.

In general you pick a component and it will have a datasheet. Or you can search for components given some parameters like maximum current or on resistance.